# How to analyze Amazon RDS queries costs (I/O)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an RDS instance that does a lot of I/O. Is there a way to figure out which queries are responsible for that I/O? I can probably figure out which queries are slow, but I'd like to actually be able to measure I/O as measured by Amazon so that I can tweak the queries and understand the impact on I/O.

Answer (score 0):

already answered here. you can also use percona toolkit that give alot of information on mysql

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171/for-a-mysql-query-how-do-you-determine-physical-and-logical-i-o